# Formatar apenas as laterais da Borda do botão

Tags: html5, css3

Existe outra forma de formatar apenas as bordas right e left, e deixar top e bottom none ?

```
border-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px;
border-right: 2px solid #444444;
border-left: 2px solid #444444;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira também, onde a propriedade `border-width` vai definir as larguras das bordas:

```css
button {
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px; /* Ordem: top, right, bottom, left */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Botão</button>
```

Ou também pode fazer:

```css
button {
  border: #444 solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Botão</button>
```

E ainda (Sugestão de [@lazyFox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/26504/lazyfox)):

```css
button {
  border: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Botão</button>
```

Comment: Editei a sua resposta @Paulo adicionando mais um exemplo. Desconhecia esse uso do `border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;` , não costumo usar mas pensava que apenas recebia um "parâmetro"

Comment: Beleza! Só vou trocar o valor pra `2px` que é o que ele colocou na pergunta. Valeu!

Comment: Me ajudou, muito obrigado  lazyFox e @PauloImon

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra sugestão é usar a *forma curta* de definir o tamanho da borda usando apenas dois valores:

```
button{
   border: solid #444;
   border-width: 0 2px; /* top/bottom = 0px, right/left = 2px */
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo:**

```css
button{
   border: solid #444;
   border-width: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Botão</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esqueceram uma variação:

```css
button {
  border: 2px #444 solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
    <button type="button">Botão</button>
```

> se duas regras tiverem a mesma força, a que for declarada por último é a que valerá.

OBS: `border: none;` ou `border: 0;` ambas são válidas, eu prefiro `border: 0` porque é mais curto;

Comment: Exactamente, nice catch